# How to use `GL.DrawArrays` to draw LineStrip using OpenTK?

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics, opentk

I'm new to **OpenTK**. I'm using this approach to draw lines with **OpenTK**.

```
public static void DrawPolygon(Point[] points)
{
    GL.Begin(BeginMode.LineStrip);  
    int numberOfPoints = points.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++)
    {
        GL.Vertex2(points[i].X, points[i].Y);
    }
    GL.End();
}
```

But it says

> `GL.Begin` is obsolete. Use PrimitiveType overload instead

Searching around I found that this approach is named [Immediate Mode](http://www.opentk.com/doc/chapter/2/opengl/geometry/drawing) and there is a second approach using `DrawArrays` method. But I couldn't find any working code sample for the second approach.

What is the code equivalent for this code sample using `DrawArrays` method or any other faster approach.

Here is what I have tried:

```
Vector2[] vertices = new Vector2[numberOfPoints];    
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++)
{
    vertices[i] = new Vector2((float)point[i].X, (float)point[i].Y);
}

int vbo;

GL.GenBuffers(1, out vbo);

GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(vertices.Length * BlittableValueType.StrideOf(vertices)), vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);

GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
GL.VertexPointer(2, VertexPointerType.Float, Vector2.SizeInBytes, new IntPtr(0));
GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, 0, numberOfPoints);


GL.Finish();
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
BeginMode.LineStrip
```

with

```
PrimitiveType.LineStrip
```

Comment: yes. Do you know how to use the `DrawArrays` approach correctly. currently when I use that approach the code consume more that 2GB of ram and shows nothing!

Comment: Did you specify a color? `GL.Color4(Color.White);`

Comment: Yes I do.   `GL.Color3(myColor);`